# Autodesk BadAuthenticationToken

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have an api that receives requests to transition states in vault. I get my 3 legged token and am able to make calls to the api and have good access_token,refresh_token, and expores_at. The api is hit every 15min to keep it alive. After about 14 to 16 hours I start receiving error 300 bad auth token. My refresh_token is still good and not expired. I have disabled all iis recycle setting and accourding to Autodesk the token should last 15 days. The error is thrown when calling the WebServiceManager. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears there is a property "CacheConnections" in the connectionManager that needs set to false using Reflections.

```
public static bool IfPropertyExistsSetIt(object instance, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var prop = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(instance, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Refresh Token lasts from 15 days. You need to get access token again using the first refresh token to keep the session running.

Comment: The refresh token has not expired when i get this error. I have tried refreshing the token and I get a new refresh token but it does not clear the error. I have the refresh token refreshing every 45min.